# Make optparse treat certain options as positional arguments

Tags: python, optparse

I have a program that takes in arguments of the form `filename:field[slice]`, which works fine. But I also wish to support the common notation that a filename of `-` means standard input. Sadly, `-:field[slice]` registers as an option with optparse (naturally), and hence does not show up as a positional argument. So I'm wondering if there is a way to get around this, for example by telling optparse that options starting with `-:` should be treated as positional arguments after all. The solution should preserve the ordering of the arguments, so `foo:bar -:cow baz:dog` should not become `foo:bar baz:dog -:cow`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that your best option is to preprocess `sys.argv` inserting a special token which you check for instead of `-`.

```
args = [ '<stdin>:'+x[2:] if x.startswith('-:') else x for x in sys.argv[1:] ]
opt_struct = parser.parse_args(args)
```

In this case, you would parse `<stdin>` as standard input in your program instead of `-`.

The transform gets a little more complicated if the `:` and the stuff after it are optional, but this is the gist of it anyway.

9 times out of 10, these problems are likely impossible to solve with `optparse`, really tricky/messy to solve with `argparse` and trivial to solve by preprocessing `sys.argv` -- But maybe that's just my experience ...

Comment: Thanks for the elegant solution, it worked like a charm (except that I had to use `sys.argv[1:]`)!

Comment: @amaurea -- right.  `sys.argv[1:]`.  I updated the post.  Thanks for the correction :)